# What handles notifications in a pure Openbox environment?

Tags: debian, xfce, openbox

I'm running Debian and logging in straight to Openbox.

I'm sure that I sometimes receive notifications, which I can actually theme and modify through Xfce's notification settings manager, but what is actually running in the background and displaying these notifications? Is it a part of Xfce?

Comment: If you have Xfce installed and active, then what do you mean by "pure Openbox environment"? Xfce uses `xfce4-notifyd-config` for the notifications. But if one runs "pure" Openbox, I would not expect to see it.

Comment: I'm planning to install Debian without a desktop environment. However, I have this fear that there are dozens of utilities and daemons that I should be running, that will simply not exist in Openbox.

I don't want to end up with a system that is crippled in the background, so I'd like to gather information on what kind of aforementioned daemons I should actually be running...

Got any advice maybe?

Comment: Sorry, was year+ late :P, provided the hard info, hopefully it will help searchers.

Comment: @TechZilla That's how SO's supposed to work, gj :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup notifications are indeed provided by the Desktop Environment, and are described in more detail, https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/. (*org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify*)

When running a pure Openbox session, libnotify messages will go unheard.  Once you install a notify daemon, you will be able to see the messages within your Openbox session.

Each of the DE's provide their own daemon, so pick whichever one you prefer.   I personally prefer notify-osd, ...had the dependencies, as written using Clutter, looks modern.

Answer (score 3):

The daemon in Xfce for displaying notifications is `xfce4-notifyd` in debian it is installed with the package of the same name.

The daemon can be started if for example `notify-send "TEST"` is run (`notify-send` comes with the `libnotify-bin` package).

But there could also be some other program making use of the notification-libraries `libnotify4`.

So to find out which programms can do this run

```
apt-cache rdepends libnotify4 --installed
```

This will give you all the packages that depend on `libnotify4` and are installed.