# Firefox notification popup timeout

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox `68.4` as a client for chat (Mattermost). When a message is received, a short notification popup appears. It only stays for few seconds and then disappears.

Where is this timeout configured ?
How can I change it ?

Ideally, I would like the popup to stay until I click with my mouse.
If that is not possible, at least I would like to increase the timeout.

**How can I do this ?**

Also, I would like to define a sound notification, whenever popup appears.

**UPDATE**

I am using plain `Openbox`, without any other desktop environment. I am not aware that I have any notification daemon. I am almost sure, the notifications are handled by `Firefox`. The pop-up window looks like `Firefox`.

Comment: Is this in your notification tray? Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: What notification manager are you using?

Comment: This is mainly handled by the desktop environment, we need precision about the used desktop in order to to give a precise answer...

Comment: @bu5hman It is libnotify for osd messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox notifications are mainly handled by the desktop environment.

**Gnome**

This is not an easy task for gnome, details on notifications delay are available [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369574/how-to-change-the-notification-timeout-in-gnome).

However, notifications in gnome should remain visible, until you move your mouse.

**KDE**

Notification settings (and delay) can be changed in the KDE system settings

```
systemsettings5 > Notification > Select "Firefox" on the drop list
```

Then adjust the delay on the desired notification, also note that this [notification applet](https://store.kde.org/p/1227099/) is probably useful in this case.

**Openbox**

In this case, this depends on the used notification daemon (precision on the system config are needed), detail for Openbox notification is available [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82150/what-handles-notifications-in-a-pure-openbox-environment).

**Alternative**

Notification can be intercepted and handled manually with a custom script/application, more details are available [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3p34xq/intercepting_libnotify_messages/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770218/how-can-i-log-all-notify-send-actions)

**Note**

Precision on the used desktop is required for a more detailed answer.

Comment: I didnt expect KDE or anything to overwrite programm parameter. Nice to know.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I use Mattermost but it appears from the website that notifications are delivered to the [system tray](https://docs.mattermost.com/help/getting-started/configuring-notifications.html)

In KDE5 you can change system popup notification timeouts in

```
System -> System Settings -> Notifications
```

If this **is** managed through the system tray then your sound notifications should be in the system settings too.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox forwards push notifications to your desktop environment's notification manager.

The settings for the notification handler are controlled in your desktop environment's setup menus.  Depending on your desktop environment you may be able to change what listener(s) handle(s) these notifications and change how they are displayed.  Normally they are handled by the systray notification handler.